# What is the "normal" filesize for an app?

Tags: iphone, filesize

My app compiles to about 80mb. I was under the impression this was quite large. However it does have video content, high resolution images and we're charging ₤3.99 for it on the App store.

What would be "large" for an app? For instance, would you say 80mb was large? What would you say the limit is (realistically).

Thank you very much

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these [high-resolution magazine apps](http://mediamemo.allthingsd.com/20100928/conde-nasts-ipad-apps-are-too-portly-blame-adobe/) are a few hundred megabytes (I know they're iPad, but the storage is the same size in each case). I think <100MB is not unreasonable.

Comment: +1 - Another good example of why it's impossible to answer objectively.

Comment: i do appologise for the subjectivity of this particular topic. I wasn't looking for a 1+1=2 answer, I was looking for an opinion. I gave enough information to illicit a subjective - yes - but still useful answer. "I think <100mb is not unreasonable" is a good answer, thank you graham. I understand that for apps with HD content and such you can get away with them being quite a bit bigger I think.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't think this can be answered objectively. You should do whatever you can to keep it as small as possible so you're not wasting storage space on the device. Just realize the app bundle's size isn't a reflection of the exectuable's size. If the executable is huge, that's a (memory) problem you should try to address. If most of it is resources, compress as well as you can without sacrificing too much (or any?) quality, and that's the best you can do.

In other words: there is no such thing as a "normal" size for an app.

Comment: I'd add that you should just keep in mind that, as a user, I might skip your app if I see its size because I might be running out of room on my device. Considering this is more on the business strategy / marketing side of things, but no less important to the aspiring indie dev. :-)

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty large.  IMO anything over 20MB is large, seeing how it requires a WiFi connection to download.  Since your well over that, I wouldn't worry about bringing it down.

Whenever possible, keep your app under 20MB.  However, there are plenty of apps that are bigger than yours.

Comment: This is kind of what I meant by "can't be answered objectively" ... we all might "feel" like we have an idea what is normal, but again, it's impossible to be objective, given some apps contain large media files. I cite rich, HD games, global map applications (those that store the map as opposed to those that get it from a web server).

Comment: You're absolutely right.  My point is there is nothing more irritating then trying to download an app (while using cellular data) and getting a message that WiFi is required.  However, often it's unavoidable to go over 20, especially when video or high resolution images are included.

Comment: Agreed, but that limitation is between Apple and AT&T. If the app has a good reason to have so much baggage with it and I can't download it until I connect to a WiFi network, my rage instantly goes to Apple/AT&T. :-)